# Как организовать передачу данных между android клиентом и сервером на java?

Tags: java, android

Делаю приложение на android, которое взаимодействует с сервером через сокеты. Сервер может принимать различные типы данных и в ответ может присылать различные типы данных. Как организовать взаимодействие? Сейчас передаю `List<Objects>`, в котором первым элементом передаю id клиента,вторым идентификатор операции, и дальше добавляю необходимые данные (всегда примитивы). На стороне сервера кастую в нужные типы. Передавать сериализуемый объект не могу, потому что имена пакетов разные. Как правильно делать?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `REST-API` Протоколов обмена данными достаточно, не думаю что стоит придумывать что-то свое, разве что "поиграться" Обычно данные передаются `http`, `https` в формате `json`

Comment: Точно, json. Забыл совсем.... Ответь, отмечу решением.

Comment: "идентификатор операции" может быть именем метода который и обрабатывает эти данные. на приёмном конце с помощью рефлексии вызывается этод метод и передаются данные. подобное у меня работаем уже в нескольких проектах

Comment: сейчас очень наплохо можно использовать протоклй websocket, у него есть и шифрованный вариант wss. очень экономичный, полный дуплекс, может передавать как текстовые так и бинарные данные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Передавать данные в виде текста в формате `json` или `xml`.